# Neo4j ShortestPath With Two Relationships

Tags: neo4j

I have a dual relationship (vertex D)-[rel1]->(vertex DB)-[rel2](vertex D)

I need the shortestPath between two elements by D using this relationships

Is tried

```
MATCH (d:D{d_pk:1})-[r1:DgoDB*]->()
MATCH p = allShortestPaths( (ALL (RELATIONSHIP IN r1)->()) - [r2:DBgoD*] -> (to:D) )
WHERE (to.d_pk = 70258)
RETURN d, r1, p
```

but but it did not work.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify your pattern a bit more? Is the path you want to find made up of both kinds of relationships (:DgoDB and :DBgoD) in any order? Or is it first a path of just :DgoDB relationships, and then the rest of the path is :DBgoD relationships? Or is it something else completely?

Comment: The original database is relational. There is a grade 3 relationship [linked_to] between two elements of the Person table, and an element of the Type table. This relationship says that an element of Person is connected to another element of Person and is of type Type, friend, father, son, mother, schoolmate, etc;
In modeling for graph databases, Person originated the vertex D, Type  vertex B and [linked_to] relationship originated vertex DB and the edges [DgoDB], [DBgoB] and [DBgoD].
Now I needed to find the shortestpath between two elements of D, so I need to go from D-> DB and then DB-> D

Comment: I'm still trying to parse this. In the meantime, it's a good idea to select node labels and relationship types which have some actual meaning according to what you're actually modeling. Graph databases tend to be good at better articulating the meaning of your data and how it's connected, but choosing labels and types that are too abstracted from what's actually being modeled prevents those meanings and connections from being clear.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your model right (and any additional clarification is more than welcome) you're looking for paths along :DgoDB and :DBgoD relationships to reach the other node.

Provided that only :DgoDB relationships connect :D to :DB nodes, and that only :DBgoD relationships connect :DB to :D nodes, then it should be enough just to specify that the variable-length pattern you're looking for includes both sets of relationships.

Something like this, maybe?

```
MATCH (d:D{d_pk:1}), (to:D{d_pk:70258})
MATCH p = allShortestPaths( (d)-[r1:DgoDB|:DBgoD*]->(to) )
RETURN d, r1, p
```

Comment: I'm studying four different methods of modeling graph databases and I've converted a relational database through the four methods and now I'm running queries on the four bases. In a modeling vertex B was replaced by parameters in the relationship that remained DgoD and there it became easier